# Doctrine time difference

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

```
SELECT count(a) FROM Entity a WHERE
     (a.timeFrom <= a.timeTo AND :start_time BETWEEN a.timeFrom AND a.timeTo)
     OR (a.timeTo >= a.timeFrom AND :end_time NOT BETWEEN a.timeTo AND a.timeFrom) 
     AND a.confirm = 1
```

Note: I need to check the availability of time slots between two time field on `getSql();` it's returning something like this

```
SELECT count(m0_.id) AS sclr_0 FROM table_name m0_ 
WHERE (m0_.time_from = m0_.time_from 
          AND ? NOT BETWEEN m0_.time_to 
          AND m0_.time_from) 
      AND m0_.confirm = 1
```

Its escaping the arguments after `OR` operator

Comment: Could you shou us the PHP code used to generate this query?

Comment: I found the solution myself it's due to the <= operator which escapes the remaining query

Comment: Just as a comment: if you avoid DQL and use QueryBuilder, you won't have these problems anymore.